# Unexpected Identifier Error when Importing a local file into AudioWorkletProcessor File

Tags: angular, syntax-error, web-audio-api

I am currently using Angular to build a video conferencing application. In one of my services, I try to incorporate the web audio api. The problem is when I try to add a script to the audio worklet using the `addModule(AudioWorkletProcessorFileName.js)` function, it throws a `SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier`. I have found that it only happens when I try to import another file into `AudioWorkletProcessorFileName.js`. When I remove the `import` statement, everything works fine. There is more complex code that I want to import, but I wanted to start off with a more simple version of `test.js` (the file I want to import). I am not sure why this is the case. Am I missing some configuration settings in Angular or something else?

In audio.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AudioContext, AudioWorkletNode } from 'standardized-audio-context';

@Injectable()
export class AudioService {
     audioCtx = new AudioContext();

     constructor() {}

     async createNewSetting(track) {
         // We need an audio context for the sound
         const srcNode = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamTrackSource(track);
         const destNode = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();

         // This will be the processor node
         await this.audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule(
          './assets/worklet/audio-worklet-processor.js'
         );

         const spatialNode = new AudioWorkletNode(
             this.audioCtx,
             'spatial-processor'
         );

         // Connect the nodes
         srcNode.connect(spatialNode);
         spatialNode.connect(destNode);

         // Return the updated audio stream
         return destNode.stream.getTracks()[0];
    }
}
```

In audio-worklet-processor.js:

```
import TEST_VAR from './test.js'; // Will throw exception when I include this

class SpatialProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("In Constructor");
    }

    process (inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        console.log("In Process");
        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor("spatial-processor", SpatialProcessor);
```

In test.js:

```
const TEST_VAR = 1;

export default {
    TEST_VAR
};
```

Comment: Hi mwong, is it possible that you test the code in Firefox? Unfortunately Firefox does not yet support import statements in AudioWorklets.

Comment: I have always used Chrome.

Comment: I just tested this in an Angular App in Chrome. It works for me. I can see the log statements.

Comment: Hmmmm very interesting...Can you send me a link to your Angular app since I want to see how you structured it and if any Angular config settings are different from mine? I created a fresh project to test, and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you upload your fresh Angular App somewhere (maybe Bitbucket or GitHub)? I tested it inside of an existing Angular App. I would have to create a clean example first. Thanks.

Comment: The repo is here: https://github.com/wongmaster3/Angular-Test. I have found out that when I navigate to another page in Angular with the audio service, it will give this exception. However, if the service is loaded on the home page, then there won't be an error. It seems there might be a problem with how routing in Angular affects the addModule() function.

Comment: Thanks for providing the test case. It turned out to be a bug in standardized-audio-context. The way it resolved relative URLs was wrong. I fixed it with [this commit](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context/commit/0596150c8956c02311008659c0cac676a07c8213). When I update standardized-audio-context to v25.1.7 (that's the version with the fix) your example works as expected.

Comment: Ah thank you so much!!

Comment: One more question. Is there a way you can use the es6 fetch function in the processor file? I tried to use fetch, but it throws an exception of 'fetch is not defined'. I am trying to incorporate webassembly code into the audio worklet processor.

Comment: The fetch API is not available from inside an AudioWorklet. You can fetch the wasm module from the main thread and then pass it via the processorOptions to the AudioWorklet. The last step would be to instantiate it there.

Comment: I'll go ahead and add an answer to this question just for the sake of completeness. Maybe someone else is going to search for it at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above this was a bug in standardized-audio-context which did not correctly resolve relative paths inside of an AudioWorklet. It should be fixed in version 25.1.7 and above.